# How can I fix this error "Cannot set properties of undefined"

Tags: discord.js

```js
const { Client, Intents, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
let client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const Keyv = require('keyv');
const keyv = new Keyv();
dotenv.config();

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', async (msg) => {
    let number = msg.content.split(' ')[1];
    if (msg.content === '!ping') {
        msg.channel.send('ping!')
    }
`
    const getGuildPrefix = async () => {
        const prefixMap = await keyv.get('prefix');
        return prefixMap ?. [msg.guild.id] || "!"
    }

// Sets the prefix to the current guild.
    const setGuildPrefix = async (prefix) => {
        const prefixMap = await keyv.get('prefix');
        prefixMap[msg.guild.id] = prefix;
        await keyv.set('prefix', `${prefixMap}`);
    }

    let prefix = await getGuildPrefix();
// Get prefix command.
    if ((msg.content === `${process.env.prefix}prefix`) || (msg.content === `${prefix}prefix`)) {
        msg.channel.send(`Your server prefix is ${prefix}`)
    }
})
client.login(process.env.token);
```

So what this code does is retreive prefix for a particular server in which   different server have different prefix, so I used keyv package for storing the prefix, but I am getting an error and this is the error message

```
    prefixMap[msg.guild.id] = prefix;
                                ^
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '857122654976606239')
    at setGuildPrefix
```

Here if the value in the key is empty, then it is supposed to return the value "!" by default. So this is almost the same code I did yesterday, but I edited the code a little bit to fix the error in getGuildPrefix, and now I am getting this error. Both the errors are caused because of undefined but I used optional chaining to fix the first one, and the getGuildPrefix is working fine, but there is now an error in the setGuildPrefix part. The thing is even if PrefixMap is undefined, the value is supposed to be "!", the code is in that way (I assume, but not very sure though).  How can I fix this error?

Comment: Guild is defined properly as u can see that it gave out the guild id in the logs

Comment: It looks that `prefixMap` is undefined. `keyv` has been initialized but not populated with any key-value pairs.

Comment: You need to write some code that does what you say: "this code does is store a prefix for a particular server so that different server can have different prefix" I don't see any such code in your posted sample.

Comment: this code was only for getting the prefix not storing it, I didn't give the full code here because it was too long. btw I fixed the error by using optional chaining (?.), so that if the term is undefined then it returns "!"

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic syntax might be wrong here, try

```
const getGuildPrefix = async () => {
        const prefixMap = await keyv.get('prefix');
        if(!prefixMap[msg.guild.id]) {
            return prefixMap[msg.guild.id];
        } 
        else {
            return '!';
        }
    };
```

Comment: still the same error, the error message is also same like last code

Comment: I was not a logical syntax error, I managed to fix that error by using optional chaining which is almost the same method used here but a bit different. So now there is no error in the getGuildPrefix

Answer (score 0):

the value which is supposed to return is !, but we gave it only in the getGuildPrefix, but we cant do optional chaining in the setGuildPrefix because it gives an error like left hand, so if keyql doesn't return a value from db again, then we can iniatite it again within the if statement again but using another if statement. we cant use this technique in the getGuildPrefix idk why, but we can use this in setGuildPrefix and we can use optional chaining in getGuildPrefix and now the error is fixed, and the code is working functionally

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async (msg) => {
    let number = msg.content.split(' ')[1];
    if (msg.content === '!ping') {
        msg.channel.send('ping!')
    }


// Use this function to get the prefix in other files.
// Use like `const prefix = await getGuildPrefix();`
    const getGuildPrefix = async () => {
        const prefixMap = await keyv.get('prefix');
        return prefixMap ?. [msg.guild.id] || "!"
    }

// Sets the prefix to the current guild.
    const setGuildPrefix = async (prefix) => {
        let prefixMap = await keyv.get('prefix');
        if (!prefixMap)
    {
     prefixMap = "!";
    }
        prefixMap[msg.guild.id] = prefix;
        await keyv.set('prefix', `${prefixMap}`);
    }

    let prefix = await getGuildPrefix();
// Get prefix command.
    if ((msg.content === `${process.env.prefix}prefix`) || (msg.content === `${prefix}prefix`)) {
        msg.channel.send(`Your server prefix is ${prefix}`)
    }
})
client.login(token)
```